# MOODLE SQL only return results where user is in same group student

Tags: moodle

```
SELECT ra.id,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ra.timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y') AS Enrolment_Date,
    c.fullname,
    IFNULL(cmc.completed, 0) as 'Activities Completed',
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cc.timecompleted),'%d-%m-%Y') AS complete_date,
    CONCAT('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/user/profile.php?id=',ra.userid,'">', u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, '</a>') AS Username
FROM prefix_role_assignments AS ra
    JOIN prefix_user u ON ra.userid = u.id
    JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON ctx.id = ra.contextid
    JOIN prefix_course c ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
    JOIN prefix_enrol e ON e.courseid = c.id
    JOIN prefix_user_enrolments ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id AND ue.userid = u.id
    LEFT JOIN prefix_course_completions cc ON cc.course = c.id AND cc.userid = u.id
    LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_items gi ON gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemtype = 'course'
    LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades g ON g.itemid = gi.id AND g.userid =u.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT cmc.userid, cm.course, COUNT(cmc.id) as completed FROM prefix_course_modules_completion cmc, prefix_course_modules cm WHERE cm.visible = 1 AND cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id  AND cmc.completionstate IN ('1','2') GROUP BY cm.course, cmc.userid) cmc ON cmc.course = c.id AND cmc.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id > 0 AND (c.id IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT(ctx.instanceid) as id 
        FROM prefix_role_assignments ra JOIN prefix_context ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
        WHERE ra.userid = %%USERID%% AND ctx.contextlevel = 50 AND ra.roleid IN ('1','9','2','3','4','10'))
    OR c.id IN(
        SELECT distinct(c.id) as id FROM prefix_role_assignments ra
            JOIN prefix_context ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
            JOIN prefix_course c ON c.category = ctx.instanceid
            WHERE ra.userid = %%USERID%% AND ctx.contextlevel = 40 AND ra.roleid IN ('1','9','2','3','4','10'))
        ) AND u.deleted = 0 AND u.suspended = 0 AND u.username <> 'guest' AND c.visible = 1 AND ue.status = 0 AND e.status = 0 AND ra.roleid = '5' 
GROUP BY ra.userid, ctx.instanceid HAVING u.firstname LIKE 'student'  ESCAPE '\\'
```

Hi all,
Im struggling here, I cant seem to get how to only return results from the above query where the user running the query (%%USERID%%) shares the same groups as the student. This is a query cobbled together from a number of other queries and works perfectly except for that one thing.

Ive tried to tack on the following in various ways into this but cant get it to work at all

```
SELECT g.name, gm.groupid, u.firstname
FROM mdl_groups as g 
    JOIN mdl_groups_members as gm ON g.id = gm.groupid
    JOIN mdl_user as u ON u.id = gm.userid AND u.id = 'student', %%USERID%%'
```

Any help at all even a point in the right direction would be great, this isnt my job role as such but Ive been tasked to make something like this happen.

Thanks for reading

Comment: `the user` running the query... shares the same groups as `the student`. how are you defining "the student"? or is it "any/all student/s"?

Comment: Last line - HAVING u.firstname LIKE 'student'  - The test student is called "Student Test" firstname = student.

Comment: HAVING u.firstname LIKE 'student' can actually be ommited completely, I need it to return all students that share same course and groups.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the subquery boils down to just some userids, but this needs to return rows.

```
        SELECT DISTINCT
             gms.userid
        FROM mdl_groups_members gms
        INNER JOIN mdl_groups_members AS gmu ON gms.groupid = gmu.groupid
        WHERE gmu.userid = %%USERID%%
        AND gms.userid LIKE 'student%'
```

If it does then it needs to link to the correct place. Now his is quiet a leap, but  and it "might" be used this way: (select * is not recommended, just an abbreviation):

```
SELECT
      *
FROM prefix_role_assignments AS ra
INNER JOIN prefix_user u ON ra.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
             gms.userid
        FROM mdl_groups_members gms
        INNER JOIN mdl_groups_members AS gmu ON gms.groupid = gmu.groupid
        WHERE gmu.userid = %%USERID%%
        AND gms.userid LIKE 'student%'
           ) sg ON ra.userid = sg.userid
INNER JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON ctx.id = ra.contextid
INNER JOIN prefix_course c ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
INNER JOIN prefix_enrol e ON e.courseid = c.id
INNER JOIN prefix_user_enrolments ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id AND ue.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN prefix_course_completions cc ON cc.course = c.id AND cc.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_items gi ON gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemtype = 'course'
LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades g ON g.itemid = gi.id AND g.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            cmc.userid
          , cm.course
          , COUNT(cmc.id) AS completed
      FROM prefix_course_modules_completion cmc
         , prefix_course_modules cm
      WHERE cm.visible = 1
      AND cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id
      AND cmc.completionstate IN ('1', '2')
      GROUP BY
            cm.course
          , cmc.userid
      ) cmc ON cmc.course = c.id AND cmc.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id > 0
AND (
c.id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            (ctx.instanceid) AS id
      FROM prefix_role_assignments ra
      INNER JOIN prefix_context ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
      WHERE ra.userid = %%USERID%% AND ctx.contextlevel = 50
      AND ra.roleid IN ('1', '9', '2', '3', '4', '10')
)
OR c.id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            (c.id) AS id
      FROM prefix_role_assignments ra
      INNER JOIN prefix_context ctx ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
      INNER JOIN prefix_course c ON c.category = ctx.instanceid
      WHERE ra.userid = %%USERID%% AND ctx.contextlevel = 40
      AND ra.roleid IN ('1', '9', '2', '3', '4', '10')
)
)
AND u.deleted = 0
AND u.suspended = 0
AND u.username <> 'guest'
AND c.visible = 1
AND ue.STATUS = 0
AND e.STATUS = 0
AND ra.roleid = '5'
GROUP BY
      ra.userid
    , ctx.instanceid
HAVING u.firstname LIKE 'student%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate the help, any idea where I would insert that though, this is where im falling over. Do I just start another select statement at the end or do I put it in the body where the other joins are? Really do appreciate the help

Comment: Sorry couldnt get that to work, would you use gms. or gmu. instead of gm.userid?

Comment: abandoned that earlier suggestion.... (but, yes, the alias in the last join was incorrect) now attempting to join into larger query and that subquery is different, bu include the filter for `the student` but that can be removed.

Comment: well it returned 0 rows which is better than what I was getting at least it is executing.

Comment: You are somewhat asking the impossible as I can't see any data. does that new subquery return any values when run separately? (see top of answer) is the column I linked it to the same type of data?

Comment: refresh, "where and" has been removed

Comment: Ahh sorry mate, I meant no offence, I have gotten it to work somewhat, it now will not show any result if you share no common groups. If you share at least one common group it now shows all results for all courses even if the user running it is not involved. Ill keep playing with it and post some results for you to see. I really do appreciate this. Closest ive ever been.